# Is there a way in python to match wild card value in a string

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I have 2 tables:

1. Report Table
2. Mapper Table.

[image: Table data image for reference]

The column 'Version' is common in both the tables.

I am trying to perform a function similar to that of VLOOKUP in Excel. i.e. For each product in Report table, I want to use 'Version' as my key and get the values of 'Answers' from the Mapper table.

Desired output:

[image: Desired output image reference]

I am using the below code to perform the task:

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd
import csv

# read csv data
df1 = pd.read_csv('report.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('mapper.csv')

left_join = pd.merge(df1,
                    df2,
                    on ='Version',
                    how ='left')
print(left_join)
```

Here is a snip of the output that I am able to generate running the code.

[image: Current output image reference]

However, the problem is I want "No" against product B.
But since the mapper table that I have used has a wild card value "%", I am unable to get the desired result. i.e. if I want to refer a version 8.0.2510.**8** or 8.0.2510.**1000**, my mapper has a generic string 8.0.2510.**%**. I cannot change the mapper.

How to perform mapping of strings with wild card values?

The code can be modified. Using pandas is not necessary. Solution with list or dictionary are also fine

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution as I couldn't find a way to merge/join 2 pandas dataframe on a regex directly.

```py
import pandas as pd

mapper = {'Version': ['6.0.270', '8.0.2510.%'],
          'Answer': ['Yes', 'No']}
report = {'Product': ['A', 'B'],
          'Version': ['6.0.270', '8.0.2510.8']}

mapper_df = pd.DataFrame(mapper)
report_df = pd.DataFrame(report)
```

mapper_df

```
      Version Answer
0     6.0.270    Yes
1  8.0.2510.%     No
```

report_df

```
  Product     Version
0       A     6.0.270
1       B  8.0.2510.8
```

Here I'm adding a new column instead of joining 2 dataframes by using `replace()` function to add matching values on `Answer` column based on regex match between `Version` columns. Note that I have replaced `%` with `*` to create a proper regex.

```py
mapper_df['Version'] = mapper_df['Version'].map(lambda x: str(x).replace("%", "*"))

to_replace = mapper_df.Version.values.tolist()
values = mapper_df.Answer.values.tolist()

report_df["new"] = report_df['Version'].replace(to_replace, values, regex=True)

print(report_df)
```

Output

```
  Product     Version  new
0       A     6.0.270  Yes
1       B  8.0.2510.8   No
```

**Edit**

Note: This solution is built to address the provided issue with provided sample data. If there are other different scenarios with wild cards, the regex build need to be updated accordingly. Simply update this line that updated `Version` column has a valid matching regex.

```py
mapper_df['Version'] = mapper_df['Version'].map(lambda x: str(x).replace("%", "*"))
```

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? `*` does not work like that in regexp, it means 0 - n times the previous character. Your code might be working because the previous character happens to be `.` which means any one character. If you're doing regexp match with text that contains dots might also lead to wrong results if you don't escape them.

Comment: You are right about the `*`. I didn't explicitly add a `.` as the previous character is a `.` resulting in `.*` at the end. That's how my code works. I agree that if there are other scenarios (which are not provided in the question) the regex need to be built accordingly.

Comment: I have added a note to my answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create an additional column with a "great common factor version" and called it `gcf_version`. It simply drops the last field after the dot in `Version`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

def removeLast(str):
  return '.'.join(str.split('.')[:-1])

# read csv data
df1 = pd.read_csv('report.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('mapper.csv')

df1['gcf_version'] = df1['Version'].map(removeLast)
df2['gcf_version'] = df2['Version'].map(removeLast)

left_join = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='gcf_version', how ='left')
print(left_join)
```

The output is like this:

```
  Product   Version_x gcf_version   Version_y Answer
0       A     6.0.270        6.0     6.0.270    Yes
1       B  8.0.2510.8   8.0.2510  8.0.2510.%     No
```

You can choose now what to drop and what to keep.